# Call to controller action keeps running -after- execution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller with a newly created action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/personintern/checkname/{dossierId}/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult CheckName(Guid dossierId, Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;

        var result = this.Manager.CheckName(dossierId, id);

        if (result == null)
            return NotFound();

        var end = DateTime.Now;
        var seconds = (end - start).TotalSeconds;

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.LogManager.Error(ex);
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the `return Ok(result)` line, the seconds timespan indicates the action is executed in about 3 seconds, which is normal for this particular request.

However, as soon as I let go, the page continues to load, even though the action has completed successfully.

What could be causing this and what can I do to find it?

Comment: what type is `result`? Maybe it contains cyclical references

Comment: @Jehof: It's a single EF instance of a table record.

Comment: Does it work well, when you replace `return Ok(result)` with `return Ok("someconstantValue")`?

Comment: Having said that, I realise I should cast it to an API model, because I shouldn't send that across the network, might be it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the result of `this.Manager.CheckName(dossierId, id)`, which was an EF record instance, to a DTO model object fixed it. The old business code I built upon returned the EF instance, which I thought was a Business object, because the namespace was very confusing!

Kudos to [Jehof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83039/jehof) for pointing me in the right direction.